# How to average multiple inputs in Python in a condensed form?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have many, many numbers to write and it is simply not efficient to write out...

```
a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
b = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
c = float(input("Enter the third number: "))
```

...when you have a thousand numbers. So how can I use the range feature maybe to get many numbers from a single input line and then also calculate the mean or average of all of the inputs?

Comment: `numbers = [float(input("Enter number %s: "%i)) for i in range(1000)]`

Comment: Are you really expecting your poor users to type in one thousand separate numbers?

Comment: @JohnGordon the input does not have to come from a human :)

Comment: True, but that's the typical use for `input()`, otherwise why not just read directly from stdin?

Comment: @timgeb: If the input doesn't come from an actual person, the prompts seem rather pointless.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Looks like work for the user of OP's program.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a **for loop** to repeatedly query for the numbers. If only the average is needed, it's sufficient to just increment a single variable and divide by the total number of queries at the end:

```
n = 10
temp = 0
for i in range(n):
    temp += float(input("Enter a number"))

print("The average is {}".format(temp / n))
```

By using the built-in [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) function and **generator comprehension** it's possible to shorten that code alot:

```
n = 10
average = sum(float(input("Enter a number")) for i in range(n)) / n
print("The average is {}".format(average))
```

Answer (score 3):

A concise way is with a list comprehension.

```
nums = [float(input('enter number {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(100)]
```

Replace 100 with any range you like. This will create a list of input numbers. You can access the n'th input number with `nums[n-1]`.

Alternatively, you could parse a single input string into a list of floats:

```
>>> nums = [float(x) for x in input('enter numbers: ').split()]
enter numbers: 1.0 3.14 7.124 -5
>>> nums
[1.0, 3.14, 7.124, -5.0]
```

I'd prefer that over a lot of prompts.

Finally, if getting the numbers from the command line is an option, you can do it like this

```
import sys

nums = [float(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
print(nums)
```

Demo:

```
$ python3 getinput.py 1.0 -5.37 8.2
[1.0, -5.37, 8.2]
```

To get the mean, issue `sum(nums)/len(nums)`, assuming that your list is not empty.